# Trying to reload a UItableview whenever my plist is updated?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, plist

I have a plist that is populated by the user within my app. I am trying to display the contents of that plist in a UITableView and it wont display until after the app is relaunched which means its not updating. Here is what I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"foodList" ofType:@"plist"];

    arrayFood = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];


}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
     [self.tableView reloadData];   
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"foodList" ofType:@"plist"];

    arrayFood = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: means you want to change the content of table as plist update ?

Comment: reload table wherever you update your plist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i see, you should be calling

```
[self.tableView reloadData]
```

after you load the data from plist to foodArray in viewDidAppear...

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you update the pList file simply call the self.tableView reloadData. Also, make sure that the data source you are using for your UITableView is updated. This datasource can be an NSDictionary, NSArray, NSMutableArray etc. The reloadData method of the tableView will trigger the cellforRowIndexPath method where you will create the UITableViewCell.

Comment: The problem is that I want to reload another view. so where the plist is being populated is a different view controller than the one that displays it if that makes sense. Is there a way to do something like
[otherViewController reloadData] or reload every time they click on the button that takes us to the new view controller? Sorry if that is confusing

Answer (score 0):

The best way to update the UITableView with newest data is to overwrite the setter method of data array.
For example your data array is arrayFood so you may have its property as strong or say retain

```
@property(nonanatomic,stron) NSMutableArray *arrayFood;
```

then you should overwrite its setter method.

```
-(NSMutableArray *)setArrayFood:(NSMutableArray *)array
{
   //set your data array here and simply call reloadData
   [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

in that way your tableView always get update whenever your data array changed.

Also use NSNotifications for plist change and update your arrayFood there.

Answer (score 0):

Using NSNotificationCenter may help you here.

In the ViewController that updates your plist, place this code when this update happens:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"plistDidUpdate" object:self];
```

In the ViewController you'll want to add this code to viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(plistDidUpdate:) name:@"plistDidUpdate" object:nil];
```

Also, add this function in the same ViewController:

```
-(void)plistDidUpdate:(id)sender{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```